# How can I prevent Mathematica to simplify basic trigonometric identities (1/Cot(x))?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm working on a code to display(Print[]) the answers of some excercises for my students. Some of the answers have parts like 1/Cot(x). I want to prevent Mathematica to transform this expression into Tan(x).

I've tried (as a suggestion from another thread)

```
Simplify[1/Cot[y], Trig -> False]
```

But it doesn't work. I can't use Hold[] either because the expression is making reference to a previous calculation and I need to evaluate it. Any tips?? I have Mathematica 11.2 and pardon my english. Thanks!!

Comment: For some reason when I apply Style to Print it display it as I wanted but I don't understand why. If I have the code

    Print[1/Cot[y]]
It doesn't work, it just display Tan[y] but If I have

    Print[1/Style[Cot[y], Hue[0.5]]]

Then it does display 1/Cot[y]

Not sure why this is the case

Comment: do not think there is a way. You can do tricks like `$PrePrint = # /. {1/Cot[z_] :> 1/Defer@Cot[z]} &;` then `1/Cot[y]` will remain as is, but then `Tan[x]` will now will become `1/Cot[x]` as well, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Chip's answer in the linked question should do what you want. If it doesn't, edit your question to explain why and we can reopen.